# How handle the existing dropdown value that is no more in dropdown list?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my problem: In Laravel 6, i have a required  element with the current options let say a, b, c:

```
<select class="form-control" name="mySelect" required>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

However, say d was a valid option previously and was saved to my back-end database. So now when I load my page, I'm setting mySelect to what is stored in the database but the select element is empty because d isn't an option anymore.

How can make it so my select element as Invalid if it has a value that is not a valid option?

Comment: u can do validation before submitting the data to database @Scott

Comment: Do you want to invalidate previous data? It might be important. You could check to see if incoming data is one of the options, if not, add the data as an option in the drop down using appendChild in JS/Jquery. I work with tables like this often. I think it is still important to display previously valid data to those previous users who had that option.

Comment: here is my simple fix for now 
`code`
<select class="form-control" name="mySelect" required>
    // d is the historical data that is already in the db
    <option value="d">d</option>
    @foreach
    ..... a
        <option value="b" selected>b</option>
    ..... c 
    @endfoeach
</select>
`code`